# Using uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, epsilon-delta

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R} $, a continuous function and differentiable, that verifie:

$|f(x)-f(y)|<=|x-y|   \forall   x,y\in [0,1]$

Prove that $\forall x,y\in [0,1] :|f(x)-f(y)|\leq1/2$.

I began with a reasoning by contradiction,
Suppose that $\exists \alpha,\beta \in [0,1]: |f(\alpha)-f(\beta)|>1/2$

Using the hypothesis we can proof easily that f is uniformaly continuous,so:
$\forall\epsilon>0 ,  \exists\delta>0,\forall x,y\in [0,1]: |x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

In particular $\epsilon=1/2$

$\exists\delta>0,\forall x,y\in [0,1]: |x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<1/2$

My problem is how to take all $x$ and $y$ whitout $|x-y|<\delta$ to reach th econtradiction and I don't know how to use the differentiability of $f$.

PS: I thought about "Mean value theorem" but I don't see any contradiction, with manipultations I found that it must be $|x-y|>1/2$.

Comment: thank you in advance

Comment: The statement you're trying to prove is false as written. Consider $f(x)=x$.

Comment: if I consider Strict Inequality, will the exercice be true??

Comment: My counterexample was a bit more difficult. It is easy to see that the sine is a nonexpansive map (i.e. Lipschitzian with Lipschitz constant 1).

@MaryMaths What about $f(x)=x/2$?

Comment: Thank you but, I did not catch the point

Comment: @MaryMaths The statement you're trying to prove is still false with strict inequality. Where did you find the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Take $$f(x)=\frac 34 x$$

then
for $(x,y)\in[0,1]$,

$$f(x)-f(y)=\frac 34 (x-y)$$

and

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le |x-y|$$
but
$$f(1)-f(0)=\frac 34>\frac 12$$

Comment: Thank you, now I understand